# $A_1,...,A_n$ are independent $\iff \forall 1 \leq k\leq n. \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Prove/Disprove:**   $ A_1,...,A_n $ are independent events If and only If for all $ 1 \leq k \leq n $ it occurs that   $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_{i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{k} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right)$

**Attempt:** I think the above statement is false. the "$ \rightarrow $" implication is correct since the result will follow by definition, but the reverse is not necessarily true but I can't seem to make up a counter example. I tried making a dice counterexample but It think that was bad idea since most dice problems have independency rooted in them. So I tried the following example based on other examples I've encountered:

Let there be a jar with $15$ balls, $5$ black,$5$ white,$5$ red. Let there be persons $a,b,c$.
$c$ takes out a ball uniformly ( we don't know what ball he takes out ) and throws it into the garbage, then, $ a $ takes out a black ball and returns it and  $b $ takes out a black ball and returns it.
Denote $ A$ as the event person $a $ pulled out a black ball,$ B$ as the event person $b $ pulled out a black ball,$ C$ as the event person $c $ pulled out a black ball.
Note that,
$ P(A)=P(B) = 1/3 $
$ P(A) = P(A|C)P(C) + P(A|C^C)P(C^C) = (4/14)\cdot (1/3) + (5/14)\cdot (2/3) = 1/3 $
$ P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(B\cap C)P(A|B \cap C) $ ... ( I don't know If it is worth continuing, I don't see if my example helps me in the refutation)

My attempt obviously will not work, I need a different example that will work... but I can't think up of anything, can you please help? I'm stuck on this problem for a long time.

Comment: Just wondering, what is $C^C$? Complement of $C$?

Comment: @Diger Yes, perhaps I should've added a remark about it.

Comment: But then $P(C^C)=2/3$?

Comment: @Diger Yes, what's the problem with it? $ P(A\cap B) = P(A \cap B | C)P(C) + P(A \cap B | C^C)P(C^C) =(4/14)^2 \cdot (1/3) + (5/14)^2 \cdot (2/3) = 0.112$ , Note that given conditioning in $C $, the events $A,B$ are independent ( similarly given $ C^C $ ).

Comment: Sorry, I was in the second line $$P(A) = P(A|C)P(C) + P(A|C^C)P(C^C) = (4/14)\cdot (1/3) + (5/14)\cdot (2/3) = 1/3 \, ,$$
or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh I see now, I erred, thanks, I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is true for $n=2$ but not for $n\geqslant 3$ : take $A_1=\emptyset$, and $A_2=A_3=\dots=A_n=A$, a set of probability belonging to $(0,1)$.

Comment: So it means  $P(\phi\cap A \cap A) = P(\phi)\cdot P(A) \cdot P(A) = 0 $. But $ P(A\cap A) \neq P(A)^2 $ unless $ P(A) = 1 $ ( but we can chose $ A \neq \Omega $ , hence we can have $ P(A) \neq  1 $ )?

Comment: If $P(A)(1-P(A))\neq 0$, then $A$ is not independent of itself.hence $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are not independent.